# import from excel with VBA to msSQL Server

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

Доброго времени суток!

Встала задача импорта(посредством VBA) некоторых данных из excel в таблицу на mssql server с уже существующими данными, если импортируемые данные новые то они должны импортироваться корректно, если импортируемые данные уже существуют, то необходимо заменить лишь некоторые столбцы. Сейчас всё это делается посредством INSERT вручную.

Прошу помощи так как не силён в VBA

Спасибо!

Comment: Если VBA - вероятно, в том самом Excel? Ну тогда это как бы экспорт, а не импорт...

Comment: Решение - подключаетесь к серверу и выполняете MERGE-запрос с внешним источником данных, в роли которого выступает таблица Excel. См. [OPENROWSET (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). Если операция регулярная - лучше написать хранимую процедуру и выполнять её.

Answer (score 1):

Работающий вариант посредством объекта ADO - Adodb

```
Sub InsertSQL()

   Dim St As String, sn As Single, CustomerName As String
   Dim Rst As New ADODB.Recordset

   sn = cells(6,5).Value ' число с плавающей точкой
   CustomerName  = cells(6,6).Value ' строка

   St = " INSERT INTO tbl_Orders (fld_Value, fld_Custom_ID) Values (" &
   St = St & Cstr(sn) & ", " & CustomerName & ")"

   ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1; Data Source=111.121.11.111; Initial 
   Catalog = BazaName; Persist Security Info=True; User ID=imyausera; 
   Password=1234546"

   Rst.CursorType = adOpenStatic
   Rst.CursorLocation = adUseClient

   Rst.Open ConStr, ConnectionString 

   Rst.Close

   Set Rst = Nothing
End Sub
```

Обратите внимание на

1. Типы переменных и соответ. типы в базе данных SQL
2. Синтаксис запроса SQL и правильность в конечном счете (генерация строки)
3. Необходимо добавить расширение
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

   4. Правильность адресации к серверу и т.д.
   5. Для замены строки в SQL таблице применяете инструкцию "UPDATE ...."